# Can't connect to webadmin Console for Neo4j

Tags: java, sockets, web, neo4j, localhost

I haven't been able to connect to the webadmin console but I can connect to shell and write cypher queries to and from the Neo4j DB.

The errors on the log are:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty6WebServer.startJetty(Jetty6WebServer.java:334)
    at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty6WebServer.start(Jetty6WebServer.java:154)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.startWebServer(AbstractNeoServer.java:348)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:183)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:86)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:49)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket.<init>(SSLServerSocket.java:181)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.<init>(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:134)
    at   sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.j ava:91)
    at    org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector.newServerSocket(SslSocketConnector.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.open(SocketConnector.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:283)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.doStart(SocketConnector.java:147)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:235)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty6WebServer.startJetty(Jetty6WebServer.java:330)
    ... 5 more
2013-09-24 20:29:02.076+0000 DEBUG [API] Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474],     reason [java.net.BindException: Address already in use]
```

There's nothing running on that port when I check with a lsof -i:7474
the only thing that shows up is the Java proccess running/being bind to the socket:

```
 COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
    java    6465 root  114u  IPv6  49348      0t0  TCP localhost:7474 (LISTEN)
```

I kill the proccess and restart the server and the same thing keeps happening.

What's going on?

Comment: Are you sure you're killing the process all the way dead?

Comment: yes kill (process id)

Comment: and after I kill it and check, it's gone from the list but when I restart the server, the same process comes up

Comment: how about `kill -9 <pid>`, not to doubt you, but I can't come up with any other ideas about how it would block itself from starting.

Comment: nope tried that same problem

Comment: you're still getting the error in the log?

Comment: yep, same error I even tried to change the port but the same thing came up

Comment: it stopped working after my computer crashed a couple days ago

Comment: It really seems you are starting the server 2 times. What platform, OS, what are the steps on a clean machine that lead to this?

Comment: I kept restarting and killing the process and the error stopped